# Exception in doCheckpoint:Operation category JOURNAL is not supported in state standby

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

i created HA-Cluster with one DataNode ,active NameNode , Standby NameNode and three JournalNode
when is was put a file to HDFS get this error:

```
put: Operation category READ is not supported in state standby
```

put command :

```
./hadoop fs -put golnaz.txt /user/input
```

NameNode log:

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.rollEditLog(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.rollEditLog(NamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer.triggerActiveLogRoll(EditLogTailer.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer.access$600(EditLogTailer.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.doWork(EditLogTailer.java:315)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.access$200(EditLogTailer.java:284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread$1.run(EditLogTailer.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.EditLogTailer$EditLogTailerThread.run(EditLogTailer.java:297)
2016-09-15 02:07:23,961 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 9 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.NamenodeProtocol.rollEditLog from 103.41.177.161:45797 Call#11403 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category JOURNAL is not supported in state standby
2016-09-15 02:07:30,547 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 0 on 9000, call org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.NamenodeProtocol.rollEditLog from 103.41.177.160:39200 Call#11404 Retry#0: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException: Operation category JOURNAL is not supported in state standby
```

Error in SecondaryNameNode log :

```
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category JOURNAL is not supported in state standby
```

and this is HDFS-Site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/root/hadoopstorage/data</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/root/hadoopstorage/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
    <value>ha-cluster</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.ha-cluster</name>
    <value>NameNode,Standby</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ha-cluster.NameNode</name>
    <value>103.41.177.161:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ha-cluster.Standby</name>
    <value>103.41.177.162:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ha-cluster.NameNode</name>
    <value>103.41.177.161:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ha-cluster.Standby</name>
    <value>103.41.177.162:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
    value>qjournal://103.41.177.161:8485;103.41.177.162:8485;103.41.177.160:8485/ha-cluster</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.ha-cluster</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
    <value>sshfence</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
    <value>/root/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.connect-timeout</name>
    <value>3000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about the automatic failover (ZKFC & Zookeeper). Without it, hdfs won't failover automatically.

You may try the following : make sure that both of your namenodes are in the *standby* state, by checking the namenodes consoles (or using the  *getServiceState* command from [Administrative commands](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html#Administrative_commands)). If so, manually trigger the transition using *-transitionToActive* command and *tail* the namenodes logs at the same time. In case of transition failure update your post with namenode logs.

Comment: yes, didnt mention anything about the automatic failover. bc i want to do failover manully